# Convert North East Coordinates to normal Latitude and Longitude

Tags: php

I have a gps device witch outputs coordonates such as this : **4425.7819N 02607.5766E** .

How can I convert them to normal latitude and longitude using PHP ? eg . **44.432395,26.125751**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems your GPS device outputs in MinDec format.

See under "Conversion from MinDec to Decimal Degree" at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion for information.

Update:

See the following function that I have written to convert it for you:

```
function convert($input)
{
    $input = ltrim($input, 0);
    $mCount = preg_match('/([0-9]{2})([^NESW]+)(N|E|S|W)/', $input, &$matches);
    if($mCount > 0)
    {
        $deg = intval($matches[1]);
        $degMin = floatval($matches[2]) / 60;
        $ret = $deg + $degMin;
        return ($matches[3] == 'S' || $matches[3] == 'W' ? '-' : '') . $ret;
    }
    return null;
}

var_dump(convert('4425.7819N'));
var_dump(convert('02607.5766E'));
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: Based on a test function I have written, I get `44.429698333333 26.126276666667` - is this correct?

Comment: What is the value for &$matches?

Comment: @Krutik - preg_match outputs the matched values to `$matches` as an output parameter.